# select-from-where query not working in codeigniter model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, select

I am trying to select the details of the users from a table in mysql database but it is not working. This is the code in my model :-

```
public function getuserdetails()
{
        $user_email = $this->input->post('email');
        $query_userdetails = $this->db->query("SELECT * 
                                               FROM users WHERE email = '$user_email' ");

        return $query_userdetails->result_array();
}
```

This is not working. But if I put the actual email id in the query instead of $user_email it works but not properly i.e if I use :-

```
$query_userdetails = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE 
                                       email = 'myemail@gmail.com' ");
```

In this case it returns a result. My controller code to accept the result is :-

```
$data['details'] = $this->model_userdetails->getuserdetails();
```

But the problem is that when I access $details in view :-

```
echo $details['name']."<br />";
```

it does not recognize 'name'. name is the field in the database where the name of the users are stored. But if I try to retrieve it in a foreach loop it is working :-

```
foreach($details as $udetails)
{
     echo $udetails['name']."<br />";
}
```

Comment: may be your form using `GET` method. Check it.

Comment: no its post. my other model is working properly. i use $this->db->where('email',$this->input->post('email')); No problem here

Answer (score 1):

Run queries as per codeigniter suggestion

$query_userdetails = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?", array($user_email));

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html search for Query Bindings

Comment: this is just giving the first name in users

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
$query_userdetails = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '". $user_email ."'");
```

Comment: do you think the problem is the following statement : - $user_email = $this->input->post('email');

Comment: @StacyJ pass $email from controller and test

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the part where only foreach loop would work.

If we use row_array instead of returning result_array() the foreach constraint to diplay goes away.

Now I want to select the name from the database where email is $user_email

Answer (score 0):

You have to write like this

```
public function getuserdetails()
{
    $user_email = $this->input->post('email');
    $this->db->where('email', $user_email)
             ->get('users')
             ->result_array();
}
```

After this, in view, you must to write like this

```
foreach($details as $udetails)
{
     echo $udetails['name']."<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like This:

**[CONTROLLER]**

```
$data = array();
$data['udetails'] = $this->UserModel->getuserdetails();
$this->load->view('welcome_message',$data);
```

**[MODEL]**

```
public function getuserdetails() {
    $user_email = 'webmaster';
    $userdetails = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE umail = '$user_email' ");
    return $userdetails->result();
}
```

**[VIEW]**

```
<?php 
 foreach($udetails as $row) 
 {
    echo($row->uname.'<br/>');
    echo($row->uname);
 }
?>
```

Comment: Try $this->db->get_where()

Answer (score 0):

Try this please it will help you.
**Model**

```
 public function getuserdetails()
    {
        $user_email = $this->input->post('email');
        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where('email',$user_email);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result= $query->result();
    }
```

**Controller**

```
$data['details'] = $this->model_userdetails->getuserdetails();
```

**view**

```
foreach($details as $detail)
{   
   echo $detail->name;
   echo $detail->email;
}
```